# In vim I want to run astyle on the file i'm on when I save

Tags: save, vim, astyle

When I save in vim I want to be able to run 'astyle sourceCodeThatImCurrentlyIn.cpp'. So a combination of :w and :!astyle source.c ?  Is this possible?

Thank you,
Ejay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Vim [auto-commands](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html):

```
:autocmd BufWritePost *.c execute '!astyle' shellescape(expand('%'), 1)
```

The `%` is replaced by the path of the current file. `BufWritePost` is called after the file is saved. There is also `BufWritePre` for doing stuff before the file is saved.

If you want to use this permanently then put it into your `.vimrc` configuration file.

Comment: @romainl: Correct, fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Don’t use `%`. Use `execute '!astyle' shellescape(expand('%'), 1)`: in `!astyle %` in `%` special characters are not escaped (and even space is special) and thus it is *completely* useless in any code you want to share.

Comment: if i'm reading this correctly, this will only run astyle on .c files right? how about for multiple formats? *.c *.cpp *.cc etc...?

Would I just do this `:auto BufWritePost *.c *.cpp execute '!astyle %'`

Comment: @EjayTumacder On files ending with `.c`. You can specify patterns separated by `,`: `autocmd BufWritePost *.c,*.cpp,*.cc …`, or, better, do `autocmd BufWritePost * if empty(&bt) && index(['cpp', 'c'], &ft)!=-1 | execute '!astyle' shellescape(@%, 1) | endif`: this will execute astyle on any file identified as C/C++ source code file (including `*.cc` and files where you manually did `set filetype=c`), but excluding non-file buffers (this is what `empty(&bt)` is for).